# I have telegram api to get messages. I want to show all messages on a django web page

Tags: django, telethon

Using the code below I am able to get all messages AND THE parts of message ( youtube url ) that need to be shown on web page. It is now required to show this data on a django based web page. Question is where do I start. For data that is coming from telegram, how can it be shown directly on the web page. ?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.types import MessageMediaWebPage, WebPageEmpty


client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reverse=True):
    if type(message.media) == type(None):
        continue
    if not type(message.media) == MessageMediaWebPage:
        continue
    if  type(message.media.webpage) == WebPageEmpty:
        continue
    if hasattr(message.media.webpage, 'display_url'):
        print('+++  display_url ', message.media.webpage.display_url)
```

Can I call a for loop inside the views. Another concern is, every time the page loads it will query data from telegram. And this can take long time. Is their a way to cache data that comes from an api so that subsequent reads are coming from the cache.

Comment: What have you tried with Django so far? You should also prefer to use methods like `isinstance` and `client.get_messages` instead.

Comment: @Lonami, I tried adding above code to views.py. It worked. How does it generally fetching data from third party source like telegram on a pythonanywhere host, work. Is it cached or is it stored in database

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django. But in Telethon v1 the only thing that is cached is input entities. Messages are not cached.